# ASP.NET Siteminder Login Redirect

Tags: asp.net, siteminder

Is there any way to find the login url configured in siteminder web agent programatically? 
I want to redirect to user to login page when there is no SMSESSION cookie.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to redirect to user to login page when there is no SMSESSION
>   cookie.

The Siteminder WebAgent itself will do that, anytime the user accesses a protected resource. So if you want to do it yourself, I would say that your Siteminder is misconfigured.